# Dúvida tabelas SQL

Tags: sql

Nas relações 1:1 eu tenho feito de outra maneira que só hoje reparei, em que eu transformo esse 1:1 para 1:N, sendo que na tabela que tem o N, a chave primária é a mesma  que a do 1, por isso é como se tivesse 1:1, mas não sei se esse método pode gerar erros?

Exemplo:

```
tabela 1
--------------
id_ficha - PrimaryKey
etc..

tabela 2
-------------
id_ficha -PrimaryKey e ForeignKey(tabela1)
etc...
```

Comment: Não entendi qual e sua duvida exatamente. É a respeito da cardinalidade? Poderia ser mais especifico?

Comment: Se você quer relacionar a tabela 1 com a 2, você precisa ter o "id" de um na outra para "amarrar" o dado, se você diz que o id é o mesmo. 1°- esses id sempre serão iguais? 2°- Se eles sempre forem iguais e você não quiser colocar o id de uma tabela na outra, essa "amarração" vai ficar a cargo do código, que sempre vai ter que pegar os "id's" iguais, e não pelo banco. Do ponto de vista do banco, seriam apenas dois campos, que por um acaso teriam valores iguais

Comment: @programmer2016, não conheço outra forma de fazer uma relação 1:1

Comment: Normalmente o que dão no colégio é, criar duas chaves primárias diferentes uma para cada tabela, e quando é relação de 1:1 a chave primaria das duas passa para chave estrangeira da outra. Essa maneira como apresentei em cima, sempre me disseram que poderia estar mal, e estou a tentar esclarecer isso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não gerará erros.
O método que será assumido será 1:1 caso não crie o FK_ID na tabela 2 relacionando-a com a tabela 1.

No entando, se estiver criando a tabela 2 para normalização, deverá ao menos adotar as boas práticas da modelagem de dados - criando na tabela 2, os respectivos PK_ID e FK_ID.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! Era isso mesmo. Eu gosto de usar maneiras diferentes que levam ao mesmo resultado, mas me aconselham sempre para seguir as regras para não haver erros, sendo que quando tento uma maneira nova fico com receio de houver futuros erros na base de dados. Vlw :)